# Не запускается docker (ошибка Cannot find module '/app/react-scripts')

Tags: javascript, docker, devops

При запуске контейнера я получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot find module '/app/react-scripts'
```

Хотя, вроде, прописал установку модуля в dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install react-scripts
CMD ["react-scripts", "start"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Структура папок:

```
├───getting-started-app
│   ├───spec
│   │   ├───persistence
│   │   └───routes
│   └───src
│       ├───persistence
│       ├───routes
│       └───static
│           ├───css
│           │   └───font-awesome
│           └───js
├───public
├───src
├───.gitignore
├───package-lock.json
├───package.json
├───README.md
```

Docker'ом до этого не пользовался никогда. Сказали обернуть, но у меня не получается

Comment: `CMD ["npm", "start"]` или `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`